# how to spell correct with knowledge base with python?

Tags: python, sparql, spell-checking, wikipedia-api, knowledge-graph

I want to use knowledge base as spell correct.

For example, when I give a word to knowledge base (like wikipedia), that knowledge base compares that word with all of wikipedia's words and finally output will be return whether most relevent word or same word (if not be incorrect).
for example, you can use that with SPARQL service (give a word and search in all of the knowledge base) but how to do that?
I know I can do that with below source code but it search only in one page. I can't find anywhere similar source code to search in all of knowledge base.

```
from rdflib import Graph,URIRef
from rdflib.namespace import RDFS, SKOS
g=Graph()
g.parse('https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q2831.ttl')
MJ=URIRef('http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2831')
for label in g.objects(MJ, SKOS.altLabel):
    print(label.value, label.language)
```

Comment: I don't get what exactly you are asking for? Text search in SPARQL Fuzzy search in SPARQL? A simple (though possibly inefficient) lookup of strings can be done with the [`CONTAINS`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-contains) function. A more efficient search is to make use of a non-SPARQL standard fulltext index search, many of the popular triple stores support such a mechanism.

Comment: For Wikidata it would be MWAPI for DBpedia it would be `bif:contains` - but those are not fuzzy, so whatever you mean with "spell correct", it might not work for you

Comment: @UninformedUser, hi thank you for your reply and your guides. Actually, you know I want to give a word to a program and it searches that word in all of the knowledge base and if it couldn't find that word it returns most relevant word. So, it is like a spell corrector isn't? for function contain does it search in all of the wikipedia? and is it compatible with python? and about non-SAPRQL, I'd appreciate if you show me a source code example that its input is a word and and it search in knowledge base.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to use Wikipedia as a spell correct.

For this task, you can use the following endpoint for get the "suggested" words:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&formatversion=2&search=<SEARCH_TERM>&namespace=0&limit=10
```

Where `<SEARCH_TERM>` is the word you want to get the suggestions.

Example:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&formatversion=2&search=micro&namespace=0&limit=10
```

Results:

```
["micro",["Micro","Microsoft Windows","Microsoft","Microsoft Office","Microphone","Microsoft Word","Microsoft Excel","Microsoft 365","Microsoft PowerPoint","Microsoft Outlook"],["","","","","","","","","",""],["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_365","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_PowerPoint","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook"]]
```

From these results, you could get the results at position `[1]`.

Python sample code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

try:
  url_api = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&formatversion=2&search=colo&namespace=0&limit=10" 
  api_call = requests.get(url_api)
  js = json.loads(api_call.text)
  print(js[1]) # position [1] has the "suggested" words
except Exception as ex: 
  print("Error: ")
  print(str(ex))
```

Result:

```
['Colo', 'Colombia', 'Colorado', 'Columbia University', 'Colosseum', 'Columbia Pictures', 'Cologne', 'Colorectal cancer', 'Columbus, Ohio', 'Columbia Records']
```